# Chrome not showing videos

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome

For some reason the videos are being displayed in Safari but not when I open it in Chrome? I don't know if I've set something wrong or if it's something else? I'm attaching a screenshot of what it looks like when opened in chrome.

[image]

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-row {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.thumbnail {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 18em;
  height: 11em
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="aminanew.mp4">
      <p>Amina</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="connienew.mp4">
      <p>Connie</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="rocionew.mp4">
      <p>Rocio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="kimnew.mp4">
      <p>Kim</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have given the path for the images correctly ? and mp4 is not an image format right ? Put a png or jpg and try if it is working. For putting videos maybe you could use html video tags

Comment: oops sorry I meant video, will <img src="aminanew.mp4"> not work with video? And yeah the path should be right!

Comment: It only works in Safari browser preview. Could you try the html video tag and see if it works

Comment: @Rocio are you sure it is working in Safari? using `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have to use `video` tag for that not `img` tag:

```css
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top-row {
  width: 90%;
  height: 70%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.thumbnail {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 18em;
  height: 11em
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <p>Amina</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <p>Connie</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <p>Rocio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <p>Kim</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is to add some information that the other answers, and various comments, don't appear to take into account or indicate a lack of awareness about.

The reason your videos were playing fine on Safari is that since Safari 11.1 (and in *Safari Technology Preview* prior to that) it supports having videos in the `img` tag. What's more, it's the ideal way to include (short) videos into a web page, as far as Safari (>=11.1) is concerned. You can read more about this [here](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2017/animated-gif-without-the-gif/). It's a very comprehensive article on this matter, and well worth a read.

The issue you were facing is that only Safari supports this. For support on other browsers you will need to use the HTML5 `<video>` tag, as pointed out by Manjuboyz in his/her answer.

I am not aware of a way (without JS) to use get the advantages of short videos on Safari using `img` tag, whilst having support for the many non-Safari browsers. With this in mind, the solution posted by Manjuboyz is what I would recommend. Namely, use `video` tags, not `img` tags.